# populate Django database my code with Faker library, when I was compiling it did not showing any error, but not populate fake data in admin page

Tags: python, django, faker

This is my first file which is the script for populating the database: ('fake_data.py') when I run python fake_data.py it showing "populating fake_data populating complated!"
[image]

This file is 'module.py
[image]

But when I am running server the fake data is not in admin page.
[image]

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Note

I don't understand why are you using `faker` but if you want to populate your database with random data then in

## fake_data.py

```
# Import your libraries here
import random

# define your here
def main():
    # Call populate
    print("Populating random data begins ...")
    populate(20)
    print("Populating random data ends ...")


# random tasks
todos = ["foo", "bar", "bazz"]


def add_todo():
    # Create and save records in database
    q = TODO.objects.create(name=random.choice(todos))
    return q


def populate(N=5):
    for counter in range(N):
        entry = add_todo()

# call your main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

- Note that if you don't use `q` and `entry` else where in your code, then remove both of them.